# Is it possible to use multiple json_object functions under one json_arrayagg function in Oracle?

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I need to create JSON that has two sets of json objects under one array. These objects contain aggregated data from several tables.  When I use json_arrayagg I get this error:

ORA-02000: missing ) keyword

The code should help explain more of what I've done and what I need.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
             'rData' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                        JSON_OBJECT(
                            'datapoints' VALUE JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('key' VALUE 'ENM008137Q00190',
                                                                      'value' VALUE tab3.column_6)),
                            'datatype' VALUE 'DATA_TYPE',
                            'id' VALUE tab1.column_4,
                            'key' VALUE tab3.column_1,
                            'timestamp' VALUE tab1.column_7),
                           JSON_OBJECT(
                            'id' VALUE tab1.column_4,
                            'key' VALUE tab3.column_1,
                            'timestamp' VALUE tab1.column_7,
                            'datatype' VALUE 'DATA_TYPE_2',
                            'datapoints' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(
                                        'key' VALUE  tab5.column_8,
                                        'value' VALUE tab2.column_9))))RETURNING CLOB)
 FROM table_3 tab3, 
      table_4 tab4,
      table_2 tab2,
      table_1 tab1,
      table_5 tab5
   WHERE tab1.column_1 = tab2.column_1
   AND tab3.column_2 = tab4.column_2
   AND tab3.column_1 = tab2.column_1
   AND tab1.column_1 = tab3.column_1
   AND tab2.column_3 = tab5.column_3
   AND tab2.latenttypeid = 1
   AND tab3.column_2 = 2952326910
   AND tab2.column_10 = 8878887
   AND tab3.column_10 = 8878887
   AND tab1.date BETWEEN '19-jun-19'
                    AND '25-jun-19'
GROUP BY tab1.column_4, tab3.column_1, tab3.column_6, tab1.column_7;
```

And here is the json output I would like:

```
{                  
    "rData": [{
               "datapoints": [
                              {"key" : "ENM008137Q00190","value" : "10"}
                         ],
               "datatype": "DATA_TYPE",
               "id": "H2hnJikUKAhGVzslBVBHqg86DnwGhh8V",
               "key": "534421188",
               "timestamp": "2019-07-05T05:33:12.000Z"
                    }, 
          {
           "key":"534421188",
           "id":"H2hnJikUKAhGVzslBVBHqg86DnwGhh8V" ,
           "timestamp": "2019-07-05T05:33:12.000Z",
           "datatype": "DATA_TYPE_2",
               "datapoints": [ 
                              {"key" : "ENM008137L0001","value" : "56.0869029"},
                              {"key" : "ENM008137L0002","value" : "59.79244788"},
                              {"key" : "ENM008137L0003","value" : "73.34481183"},
                              {"key" : "ENM008137L0004","value" : "43.94661396"},
                              {"key" : "ENM008137L0005","value" : "80.71909567"},
                              {"key" : "ENM008137L0006","value" : "97.2707082"}
                    ]
                    },{
               "datapoints": [
                              {"key" : "ENM008137Q00190","value" : "9"}
                         ],
               "datatype": "DATA_TYPE",
               "id": "A1JnnNjUKAhGVzslBVBHqg86Dnw52Ccj",
               "key": "534421164",
               "timestamp": "2019-07-05T04:27:45.000Z"
                    }, 
          {
           "key":"534421164",
           "id":"A1JnnNjUKAhGVzslBVBHqg86Dnw52Ccj" ,
           "timestamp": "2019-07-05T04:27:45.000Z",
           "datatype": "DATA_TYPE_2",
               "datapoints": [ 
                              {"key" : "ENM008137L0001","value" : "88.0869029"},
                              {"key" : "ENM008137L0002","value" : "88.79244788"},
                              {"key" : "ENM008137L0003","value" : "88.34481183"},
                              {"key" : "ENM008137L0004","value" : "82.94661396"},
                              {"key" : "ENM008137L0005","value" : "99.71909567"},
                              {"key" : "ENM008137L0006","value" : "88.2707082"}
                    ]
                    }]
}
```

There are 2 json_objects under the "rData" array, these are the two data sources that I wanted aggregated, but I'm not sure if that's possible with the current functions.

I apologize for the code, I've tried to give you the least amount of info needed to help with this.  And of course any help is always appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your data model. In your expected output, it looks like your array has 4 elements, 2 repeated twice. Would they normally have unique keys, or some way of defining a set of fields which are always unique?

Comment: JSON_ARRAYAGG only takes 1 argument, which is a "column". So you can only pass one thing at a time to it, but you could use e.g. a CASE statement to include multiple different kinds of JSON_OBJECTS or values in that column, depending on the value of other columns in the row.

Comment: ok, thank you.  Yeah, the elements are repeated in different objects within the array.  I'm not sure why "they" need it that way, but it is what it is.

Comment: I just mean - all of your rData objects have the same id, key, timestamp, etc. Is that what your actual data looks like?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I copied and pasted, i can make the change so it's less confusing.